# Expose SOAP Endpoint With cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws

Tags: spring-boot, cxf

I am trying to expose `cxf web services` from my Spring Boot Application. I am trying to use the `cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws v3.2.6`. The documentation for the starter is a bit out of date. The examples shows the following for exposing and endpoint.

```
@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint() {
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, new HelloPortImpl());
    endpoint.publish("/Hello");
    return endpoint;
}
```

But now the `EndpointImpl` takes 3 arguments and I am trying to understand how to construct one.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake, I was using the EndpointImpl from the wrong package. I was trying to use org.apache.cxf.endpoint.EndpointImpl and not org.apacke.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl